# Job executes during launch application

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a problem with my Spring Batch job. Every time when I launch my app my job execute with last parameters from `batch_job_execution_params`. It create problem for me, because it damages my data, how I can disable it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a Runner will be created and all jobs in the context will be executed on startup.
Disable this behavior with `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`.

Alternatively, discrete Job names to execute on startup can be supplid bye the User with a comma-delimited list: `spring.batch.job.names=job1,job2`. In this case the Runner will first find jobs registered as Beans, then those in the existing JobRegistry.

Read more: [BatchAutoConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.html)